# How to get Camera working on iPad inside UIPopoverController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to write iOS app that uses camera or photo library to take pictures. This is my first iOS app so I have no experience. I've found  several examples how to do it for iPhone and replaced modal window call `presentViewController` with `IUPopoverController`. This works fine for photo library (`imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`) but for camera ( `imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` ) have the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The content view controller argument must be the root of its associated view controller hierarchy.'
```

using Xcode 4.6
test for iOS 6.1

My code:

```
- (void) useCamera:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: imagePicker];
            [_popover presentPopoverFromRect: _popoverCenter inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                               animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        _newMedia = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Camera failed to open"
                              message: @"Camera is not available"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Is it possible to show camera inside popover on iPad?
Thanks.

Comment: What you have should work fine. However, most people would rather that you present the camera as a full screen view. While a `UIImagePickerViewController` with a source type other than camera must be in a popover on the iPad, the camera can be displayed just like on the iPhone - in a full screen modal view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy How can I launch full screen modal view controller on iPad? There is mess on the web due to differences between iPhone, iPad and iOS versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following answers the OP's comment about how to show the camera fullscreen on the iPad.

Change your code to this:

```
- (void) useCamera:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];

        _newMedia = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Camera failed to open"
                              message: @"Camera is not available"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot try this on real device right now but on the iPad simulator I have the following error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'

Comment: That error only appears if the image picker source type is not `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`. For non-camera types you must use a popover on the iPad. Since the simulator has no camera, you can't test my answer in the simulator.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try tomorrow on the device.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)showCamera
{
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

// Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
// movie capture, if both are available:
cameraUI.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

// Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
// trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

[controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
}




- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *) picker {

[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
[picker release];
}

// For responding to the user accepting a newly-captured picture or movie
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

// Handle a still image capture
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (editedImage) {
        imageToSave = editedImage;
    } else {
        imageToSave = originalImage;
    }

// Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
}

// Handle a movie capture
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
                moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}

[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
[picker release];
}
```